# Reusing algo logic for different implementations via inheritence in java

Tags: java, algorithm, inheritance, data-structures

I am trying to implement Graph data structure in java.
Below are the classes:

```
interface Graph<N,E> {
    addNode(N nodeData);
    createEdge(N src, N dest, E edgeData);
    //and many more api methods
}

class GenericGraph<N,E> implements Graph<N,E> {

    Set<Node<N,E>> vertices;

    static class Node<N,E> {
        private N node;
        private Set<Edge<N, E>> adjacencyList;

        // getters and setters
    }

    static class Edge<N, E> {

        private E edgeData;
        private Node<N, E> src;
        private Node<N, E> dest;

        // getters and setters
    }

    //******** API methods implementation*********

    Node<N, E> findNode(N nodeData) {
        Node<N, E> node = new Node<>(nodeData);
        if (vertices.contains(node)) {
            for (Node<N, E> tempNode : vertices) {
                if (Objects.equals(tempNode, node)) {
                    node = tempNode;
                    return node;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    Node<N, E> createNode(N nodeData) {
        Node<N, E> node = findNode(nodeData);
        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node<>(nodeData);
            vertices.add(node);
        }
        return node;
    }

    @Override
    public void addNode(N nodeData) {
        createNode(nodeData);
    }

    // other api methods
}
```

Here I have created two nested classes : Node and Edge

One graph object can have many nodes.

One node object can have a list of adjacent vertices.

Adjacent vertices are considered as Edge , which contains

```
->src node
->dest node
->edge relation bw the two
```

GenericGraph api methods use class Node and Edge for implementation.

Till now everything works fine.

Now I want to make some other classes that have some extra feature than GenericGraph, like BfsGraph , DfsGraph etc.

BFS algo needs 3 extra parameters for their node:

```
->color 
->parent
->distance
```

I was thinking to create BfsGraph like this :

```
class BfsGraph<N,E> extends GenericGraph<N,E> {

    //access public,protected and default methods of GenericGraph

    private enum NodeColor {
        WHITE, GRAY, BLACK;
    }

    static class BfsNode<N,E> extends GenericGraph.Node<N,E> {
        private NodeColor color = NodeColor.WHITE;
        private Integer distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        private Node<N, E> parent;

        BfsNode(N node) {
            super(node);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this design is , I have to copy each method from GenericGraph and reimplement it in BfsGraph acc to its own need (Node will change to BfsNode).

In future If I want to make some other implementation, then I again need to copy and modify all methods.

The algorithm/logic written in GenericGraph must be reused not rewritten.

Please suggest me a new solution or any modification.

Comment: (While `BfsGraph` _sounds_ off,) Please provide _one_ example of rewriting an algorithm instead of reusing it from (`Generic`)`Graph` (and not doing exactly the same thing). (You know you can qualify member access/invocation using `super`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like the subclass needs to be able to control two things:

- The created `Node` instances must be instances of a subtype of `Node`.

  - This can be handled by creating a `protected` method in `GenericGraph`, called `createNode`, that just instantiates the `Node`. `GenericGraph` can then call that method whenever it needs a `Node` instance; and subclasses can override that method to provide the right subtype of `Node`.
  - I notice that you already have a `createNode` method, but it has other logic besides just creating the node. You should rename that method to something that captures its full purpose.
- The `findNode` method needs to be declared as returning the appropriate subtype of `Node`.

  - This can be handled by having the subclass override `findNode`, but with the override simply delegating to the superclass and performing the appropriate cast, like so:

    ```
    BsfNode<N, E> findNode(N nodeData) {
        return (BsfNode<N, E>) super.findNode(nodeData);
    }
    ```
  - If you have a bunch of methods like this, then you might look into having `GenericGraph` actually take its node-type as a type parameter, so that this can be handled via the magic of generics rather than requiring explicit overrides. But it doesn't sound like you're to the point where that approach would be worthwhile.

Comment: I was considering to use inheritence for some scenarios of my need, but this design looks incorrect. But your solution helped me to extend this design to some level. So creating BfsGraph is totally wrong solution.But anyway thanks.